Перемешать элементы массива PHP
Есть два массива
var_dump($postsIdNewsArr);
array(2) { [0]=> int(243) [1]=> int(219) }

var_dump($postsIdArticlesArr);
array(2) { [0]=> int(242) [1]=> int(202) }

Нужно получить вот такой массив
[243,242,219,202]

Это нужно для выводе постов в WordPress из двух типов постов.
Как это сделать?

shuffle все.. а нет не все, это слияние а не перемешать... array_merge

array_merge не делает перемешку через один. выйдет просто 243,219,242,202

Используйте такой код.
$a = [243, 219];
$b = [242, 202];

$maxlen = max( count( $a ), count( $b ) );

// Make both arrays having the same length.
$a = array_pad( $a, $maxlen, 0 );
$b = array_pad( $b, $maxlen, 0 );

// Make sure both arrays have the same indices.
$a = array_values( $a );
$b = array_values( $b );

$joined = [];

// Perform the joining.
for ( $i = 0; $i < $maxlen; $i++ ) {
    $joined[] = $a[ $i ];
    $joined[] = $b[ $i ];
}

var_dump( $joined );


Все получилось. Спасибо!

При должном умении последние 7 строк сворачиваются в $joined = array_merge(...array_map(null, $a, $b));
